# Abrir modal en segunda página visitada

Tags: php, modal, cookies

Necesito ayuda con algo q me está volviendo loco...es sencillo pero no logro dar en el punto.
El tema es que en un sitio web tengo q abrir un modal en la segunda página q visite el usuario, independientemente de cual sea la primera url q visitó. Además, hay ciertas url internas que no deben tomarse en cuenta para esto.

Yo hice lo siguiente en el footer:

```
$ru = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 1);

    if ( ! preg_match('/^(seguros-de-viaje-working-holiday|cursos-online|beneficios|working-holiday-elegi-tu-proximo-destino|guias)/', $ru) ) :

        if ( isset( $_COOKIE['visited_page'] ) && $_COOKIE['visited_page'] == '1' ) :

            echo '<script type="text/javascript">
                setTimeout(function(){ $("#modalEbook").modal("show") }, 3000);
            </script>';

            setcookie('visited_page', '2');

        else :

            setcookie('visited_page', '1');

        endif;

    endif;
```

Pero no sé por qué me crea dos cookies con mismo nombre, distinto valor, y no imprime el js.

[image: cookies]

Comment: Que tal si intentas ponerle el path a la cookie en ambos llamados? `setcookie('visited_page', '2', 0, "/");`

Comment: Gracias @Pipe! con esto dejó de duplicarme la cookie, pero el sitio tiene un gran problema de caché que me complicó la existencia :/  finalmente lo resolví usando variables de sesión